# Reason for audio speaker diaphragm shape

Tags: acoustics, design

Why are the diaphragms on audio speakers usually a cone with a dome in the centre? I don't know much about acoustics but my guesses would be:

- it just empirically sounds better, the design was found through trial and error
- an acoustically better shape (perhaps a flat panel or a larger dome) is not structurally rigid for vibration, the cone shape is rigid and relatively flat
- the cone/dome somehow causes interference effects that give directionality to the sound waves

Could someone shed light on the physics behind this design choice?

Comment: Did you try using these things called "search engines" for, say the phrase "history of speaker design" ?